# Let $p$ be a prime, then does $p^{\alpha} \mid |G| \Longrightarrow p \mid Aut(G)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group, and let $p^{\alpha} \mid |G|$, where $p$ is a prime. Now does this imply $p \mid |Aut(G)|$?

Clearly if $|G| \leq 2$, then the Automorphism group is the trivial group, so one can see that this need not be true for $\alpha =1$. I am curious to know for higher powers of $\alpha$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $P$ be a Sylow p-subgroup of $G$.  Now $G/Z(G)$ embeds in $Aut(G)$, so we can reduce to the case where $P\le Z(G)$, so $G=P\times H$, where $(|H|,p)=1$, and $P$ is abelian.  Now if $\alpha>1$, then there will always be an element of order $p$ in $Aut(P)\subset Aut(G)$.  You can see this by looking at cyclic groups of order $p^m$ with $m>1$, and elementary abelian p-groups of dimension greater than $1$.

Steve

Comment: Possibly dumb question: Why is Aut(P) contained in Aut(G)? It is not clear to me that every automorphism of P extends to G.

Comment: @David Speyer: because $P$ is a direct factor of $G$.

Comment: Oh, I see. You're skipping a lot of steps, right? Central --> normal. H normal and GCD(|H|, |G/H|)=1 --> semidirect product (Schur--Zassenhaus). Semidirect + central --> direct. Or is there a shorter way I'm missing?

Comment: Because $P$ is central, one can apply Burnside Transfer theorem, for example, to get $G=P\times H$, but sure, Schuz-Zassenhaus works as well.

Answer (score 4):

Cyclic.

[15char]

Comment: +1 for this is a valid answer before OP edited his question to exclude $\alpha = 1$.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the question that I answered (and its title) was whether "p^a divides |G| implies p^a divides |Aut(G)|".   A side effect of the editing is that downvotes occur for correct answers that become incorrect.